# Xpath is not extracting what it should extract

Tags: python, xpath, scrapy

I am using Scrapy to parse a website. This is one product [link](http://www.goodearth.in/ratnakara-design-journal/p-2060).

The xpaths that I have tried to extract prices of products are:

```
sel.xpath ('//div[@class="product-price"]/input/div[@id="product_price"]/text()').extract()
sel.xpath ('//div[@id="product_price"]/text()').extract()
sel.xpath ('//div[@class="product-size-qua-info"]/div[@class="product-price"]/input/div[@id="product_price"]/text()').extract()
sel.xpath ('//div[@class="product-size-qua-info"]/div/input/div[@id="product_price"]/text()').extract()
sel.xpath ('//div[@class="product-size-qua-info"]/div/input/div/text()').extract()
sel.xpath ('//div[@class="product-size-qua-info"]/div/div/text()').extract()
sel.xpath ('//div[@class="product-size-qua-info"]/div//div/text()').extract()
sel.xpath ('//div[@class="product-size-qua-info"]/div[2]/text()').extract()
sel.xpath ('//div[@class="product-size-qua-info"]/div[2]//text()').extract()
sel.xpath ('//div[@id="product_price"]//text()').extract()
```

None of them is working. Some are just random tries.

What is the correct xpath to extract price of product from the [url](http://www.goodearth.in/ratnakara-design-journal/p-2060).?

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that the price and the size are retrieved by a javascript function. That explains why you don't see it in the response, but you see it in the DOM in your browser. This is not a scrapy specific issue.

Since this website relies heavily on javascript, browse the page code source instead of inspecting elements with firebug or chrome developer tools. Although it's perfectly feasible (and more efficient) to parse this website with scrapy, you could use Selenium, which supports javascript.

To get the price and size, you have to perform two additional POST requests to
http://www.goodearth.in/Wishlist.ashx, with the following parameters:

size:
ACTION=CheckInventoryforSizes&ProductID=2060&VariantID=2060&Sizes=&ChosenColor=FFFFFF-Multi&isProductDetails=true

price:
ACTION=GetProductPrice&ProductID=2060&VariantID=2060&ChosenSize=&ChosenColor=FFFFFF-Multi&View=productdetail

Comment: +1. That said, I might go with JavaScript directly written against PhantomJS rather than the more heavyweight approach of using Selenium attached to an out-of-process browser.

Comment: I'm no expert in Selenium, but I think you can use PhantomJS as a webdriver to selenium. This way you still get to write python ;-). Having said this, I would code this with Scrapy anyway.

Comment: Sure -- it's just that Selenium+PhantomJS involves considerably more moving parts than PhantomJS alone, with all that implies about performance, resource usage, and ease of debugging; how to make the call depends on just how much one cares about using a well-designed language. :)

Answer (score 0):

By the look of it, pricing is always contained in a single div with id=product_price.

It also looks well written in that there is no duplicate id=product_price on the product pages

You can therefore just simply use:

```
//div[@id='product_price']/text()
```

What happened when you tried sel.xpath ('//div[@id="product_price"]/text()').extract()?  This should be the correct pattern, the only difference being that I switched my single & double quotes.

It may seem a trivial change, but try:

```
sel.xpath ("//div[@id='product_price']/text()").extract()
```

Comment: It was blank. It didn't retrieve the price. I know it's obvious, but still it is not extracting it. 

Tried the change suggested by you, it is still not extracting the price.

Thanks BTW.

Comment: Do you have a console on your browser?  I've just tried this and it works, so I'm thinking it might be a scrappy issue.  Try this in your browser console: $x("//div[@id='product_price']/text()")